# NHibernate inner join on non primary key xml mapping

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I have two tables, for example: 
`FirstTable(firstID, field1), SecondTable(secondID, firstID, field2)`

I have an xml mapping:

```
<class name="testClass" 
             table="SecondTable"
             lazy="false">
    <id name="ID" column="secondID" type="Guid">
      <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Field2" column="field2" type="string"/>
    <join table="FirstTable">
      <key column="firstID"/>
       <property name="Field1" column="field1"/>
    </join>
  </class>
```

The problem is that as a result I want to get a query like:

```
select * from SecondTable st
inner join FirstTable ft on st.firstID = ft.firstID
```

but now query looks like

```
select * from SecondTable st
inner join FirstTable ft on st.secondID = ft.firstID
```

Is it possible to join not on a primary field?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900737/how-would-i-join-a-table-on-a-non-primary-key-field-using-nhibernate-mapping-byc

Comment: Thanks, I saw this topic, but didn't understand how exactly I can use it in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should respect related field like "keys" to get your related data.
But You can join tables by any field since they have same value type.

Also, you could understand how 'join' works seeing the following link for basics.
https://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Your code would be right if seconId was an FK pointing to firstId column on firstTable, also secondId could be a PK too, so You could remove firstId column from the secondTable, but it would be out of the best pratice. See this - https://ayende.com/blog/3961/nhibernate-mapping-join

So the code should be something like this, where you SecondTable should have a property pointing to firstID ointo another class to be related. I couldn't test over here, I'm at work.

```
<class name="SecondTable" 
             table="SecondTable"
             lazy="false">
    <id name="secondID" type="Guid">
        <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>
    <property name="secondID" type="Guid" />
    <property name="field2" type="string"/>
    <many-to-one name="firstID" column="firstID"/>
</class>
<class name="FirstTable">
    <id name="firstID" type="guid">
        <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="Field1"  type="String"  />
</class>
```